# Kia Spectra 2008 LX timing belt

Tags: timing-belt, timing

This car's maintenance history says it was serviced by Kia dealer at 70K in 2015. All other belts look new. When i opened the timing cover, belt looks like attached picture. Now it has 104K. Confused whether they have changed the belt or not. Do i need to change it?[image]

Comment: This may be due to my lack of experience when compared to those who have been in the industry for a long time, however, in my experience timing belt age is very difficult to guess. I've had a belt with nearly 200k miles and still had the writing on it. One thing that I've noticed in worn belts is the the smooth side becomes shiny as it wears. As Solar Mike says if you're not sure just replace it. No reason you can't and that way you know it's new. In the future, if you want peace of mind ask for the old parts back before they start working on it. Best of luck!

Comment: even if you do not drive a car the timingbelt will dry out over time and get brittle so to be on the safe side it is best to change it,i am not saying you have to change it now it is only my opinion about this.

Answer (score 0):

So it has done 34k since the belt was changed.

You say the other belts look new - but have you considered that this belt has both sides used, while other belts don't and so they look "clean" on the side you see....

It looks like it is a dusty environment... But there does not seem to be any signs of oil contamination.

If this worries you that much, then yes you can change it.

Here is a link to a pdf giving the change intervals:

https://assets.gates.com/content/dam/gates/home/resources/resource-library/catalogs/timingbeltreplacementguide.pdf

According to that it is inspect at 60k, replace at 80k, but as I said change it if you wish - no rules against changing early - it's your peace of mind and your money.

Answer (score 0):

When a routine service report says " all belts" , I think it is a 99% chance they mean fan ,water, AC, etc, belts, NOT timing belt. Change the timing belt.